# How to avoid cmake to read in its "system cache" $HOME/.cmake/

Tags: linux, cmake, caffe

When I run `cmake` with some projects such as `caffe` or `gflags`, it writes some information at the system level. Specifically, on a linux system, it generates some directories such as `$HOME/.cmake/Caffe` and `$HOME/.cmake/gflags`

My problem is that this information is hereafter used for any project I compile. As a consequence, the programs referenced in `$HOME/.cmake` are (partially) found, even if I do not want it (as far as I am concerned, I define external variables to control with external programs `cmake` is allowed to consider for a given compilation).
y current solution is to delete the directory `$HOME/.cmake` when needed (i.e before compiling my new program). I consider to add a `rm -rf $HOME/.cmake` in `.bashrc` but this not fully satisfactory (nor sophisticated!). Could anyone propose a better solution ?

**NB**: the expression "system cache" in the question is probably wrong. I would be grateful to get a better term. Thank you for any feedback on this (actually, if I knew the correct expression, I may have already found the solution on the web...)

---

Edit:

Once you know the "system cache" is actually the *[User Package Registry](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#user-package-registry)* the answer is easy. See below...

Comment: What specific version of CMake is writing to `$HOME/.cmake`? That seems utterly broken or misused. I've never encountered CMake writing to such directories.

Comment: It is the version 3.5.1 (question edited). My system is Kubuntu 16.04 but I had a similar behavior on ubuntu 14.04 with cmake 2.8.12.2.

Comment: A colleague of mine told me it can result from the command `export(PACKAGE caffe)` in the caffe program. It is the "user package registry".
https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Package_Registry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory `$HOME/.cmake` is the *User Package Registry*. To avoid `find_package()` to search in this directory, use option `NO_CMAKE_PACKAGE_REGISTRY`. See point 6 of its documentation:

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html

Comment: Note that `find_package()` is then in "Config mode" and thus look for `<package>Config.cmake` files only (can't find `Find<package>.cmake` files)

Comment: cmake ... -DCMAKE_FIND_USE_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=0 to disable this abomination project-wide. Seems like my cmake invocation will hit the MAX_ARG_STRLEN limit eventually :-(